# Annotating an annotated field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to `Count` on a field that is generated by a previous `Count` in Django. Here is a simplified model:

```py
class CountryUpdate(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

There is a new entry every time some country is updated. Computing the number of updates per country is fairly documented:

```py
CountryUpdate.objects.values("country").annotate(total=Count("country"))
```

What I would like to do now is count how many country has been updated X times.

Basically, if I had the following entries:

| Country | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Germany | 2021 |
| Germany | 2022 |
| France | 2021 |
| Italy | 2021 |
| Spain | 2021 |

I would like the following output:

| Number of updates | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

I tried annotating the previous queryset but it does not work.

```py
value = (
    CountryUpdate.objects
    .values("country")
    .annotate(total=Count("country"))
    .values("total")
    .annotate(global_total=Count("total"))
)
```

This gives the error

```
Cannot compute Count('total'): 'total' is an aggregate
```

This SQL query outputs exactly what is needed but I don't manage to put it in Django:

```sql
SELECT total, count(total)
from (SELECT "country_update"."country",
             COUNT("country_update"."country") AS "total"
      FROM "country_update"
      GROUP BY "country_update"."country") as t
group by total;
```